# DIC values in JAGS

Tags: r, glm, bayesian, jags, winbugs

What could be wrong if the output for a JAGS model keep showing that DIC statistics not available. All efforts made to retrieve DIC with the extract() function doesn't work and even using model$dic doesn't produce the DIC. Yet, all other statistic summary and plots are available.

Comment: Take a look again at [ask]. It's unlikely anyone can do more than guess with so little information

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.